# How can I include a php file in ajax call in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to include a php file

in the file that ajax call. For example, the code below, the .ajax url is search.php, so I want to include'fiel.php'; in my search.php, how can I do that?

```
$.ajax({
    url:'search.php',
    data:{ search_text: $(".result_tag").text()
},
    error: function(){
        $('#find_members').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
},
    success: function(data){
        $("#find_members").html(data);
},
    type:'POST' 
});
```

search.php

```
<?php
//this is search.php

include 'file.php';

echo test(); //try to testing
?>
```

file.php

```
//this is file.php
<?php
function test(){
echo"hello";}
?>
```

The HTML

```
<div id="find_members"></div>
```

Comment: You would use a PHP `include 'feil.php';` statement in search.php.

Comment: I had tried that already, but it doesn't work. So that is why I want to know what did I do wrong?

Comment: We cannot know without seeing your PHP code. On the surface your AJAX code looks a little out of shape too.

Comment: I had edit my code. If I put the function test() inside search.php, it has no problem to call it. if I put it into the file.php, a separate php, and I cannot include it in search.php

Comment: Thanks for your time. I had figure it out. It is sytanx error.

Answer (score -1):

Try to include 'fiel.php' into 'search.php' file